# Transition effect is not working when element is no longer display:none (CSS + JQUERY)

Tags: css, ajax

The transition effect doesnt work, if use visibility: hidden instead setting display to none the transition works but the invisible element fills a void space unlike display:none does, I think it regards to some asynchronicity process, there is no concurrency css, all css I have is below:

Css:

```
    .vendors_plugin_request_user_confirmation.hidden{
        display:none;
    }

    .vendors_plugin_request_user_confirmation.open{
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        right: -5000px;
        box-radius: 10px;
        padding: 30px;
        background: #feff68;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        opacity: 0;
    }
```

Jquery (ignore ajax):

```
     $('.vendors_plugin_request_user_confirmation').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.vendors_plugin_request_user_confirmation').addClass('open');
            $('.vendors_plugin_request_user_confirmation.open').css('opacity','1');
            $('.vendors_plugin_request_user_confirmation.open').css('right','0px');
            $('.confirm_vendor_submit').off('click').on('click', function(){
                    $('.vendors_plugin_request_user_confirmation.open').css('opacity','0');
                    $('.vendors_plugin_request_user_confirmation.open').css('right','-5000px');
                    $('.vendors_plugin_request_user_confirmation').removeClass('open');
                    $('.vendors_plugin_request_user_confirmation').addClass('hidden');
                    $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    data: {
                        action: 'show_cadastro_vendors',
                        submit_vendor: true,
                        form_data: formData,
                        doing_click_ajax:true
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('#wpbody').html(response);
                    }})
                }
              );

            $('.deny_vendor_submit').off('click').on('click', function(){
                $('.vendors_plugin_request_user_confirmation.open').css('opacity','0');
                $('.vendors_plugin_request_user_confirmation.open').css('right','-5000px');
                $('.vendors_plugin_request_user_confirmation').removeClass('open');
                $('.vendors_plugin_request_user_confirmation').addClass('hidden');
            }
            );
```

Setting max-height to 0, will make the element not to fill as large as before but it's still filling even if its visibility is set to hidden, if I set max-height to 0 and position absolute (all classes), the hidden element doesnt fill it anymore, but my transition animation will overlap others elements, if I set position relative back the problem is the same when changing display

Ignore obvious problems, jquery loading, css conflicts etc.... It's not it.